# Simple HTML DOM: accessing html elements within results

Tags: php, html, dom

I'm trying to get a better understanding of PHP Simple HTML DOM and am kinda stuck on the following.

I am trying to retrieve information from one of my user pages by using the following code :

```
$dom = file_get_html('http://127.0.0.1/comments/top-commenters/');
foreach($dom->find('tr[id*=commenter]') as $result) {
print_r($result->innertext);
}
```

Which produces for each commenter profile ($result->innertext) the following :

```
<td class="Position"># 3 </td>        
<td class="img" align="center">  
<a href="/images/users/814ocnqlN6.jpg">
<img src="/images/users/814ocnqlN6.jpg" info="Image" border="0"/></a>  
<a uid="814ocnqlN6"></td>        
<td> <a  href="/profiles/280-5956816-3096127"><b>User 3.</b></a>
<div class="tiny"><a href="/comments/?user=814ocnqlN6&sort_by=MostRecentComment">Most recent comments</a></div> 
</td>        
<td class="NumCredits"> 471 </td>        
<td class="NumComments"> 5.439 </td>     
<td class="PercUpVotes"> 93% </td>
```

Now if I would like to access within each result (same foreach loop)  for example :

```
<td class="Position"># 3 </td>
```

And

```
<td class="NumComments"> 5.439 </td>
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$dom = file_get_html('http://127.0.0.1/comments/top-commenters/');
  foreach($dom->find('tr[id*=commenter]') as $result) {
    print_r($result->find('td.Position'));
    print_r($result->find('td.NumComments'));
  }
}
```